# Strange behaviour if foreign_sortby used in IRRE records

Tags: extbase, typo3-8.x

I try to sort IRRE records by start (a date) automatically with foreign_sortby in the parents TCA with:

```
    'holidays' => [
        'exclude' => true,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:my_extension/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_myextension_domain_model_feusers.holidays',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'inline',
            'foreign_table' => 'tx_myextension_domain_model_holiday',
            'foreign_field' => 'feusers',
            'foreign_sortby' => 'start',
            'maxitems' => 9999,
            'appearance' => [
                'collapseAll' => 1,
                'levelLinksPosition' => 'top',
                'showSynchronizationLink' => 1,
                'showPossibleLocalizationRecords' => 1,
                'showAllLocalizationLink' => 1
            ],
        ],
    
    ],
```

This works fine in BE an FE. But the field start is with this setting no more visible in the BE form of the parent record.

The child has only 2 date fields, start and end.

**Child record with start field:**
[image: The child record]

**Parent record with missing start field:**
[image: The parent record with missing start field]
<sub>(source: [honrath.de](https://honrath.de/parent.png))</sub>

**What is my mistake?**

Answer (score 0):

**The solution** is replacing:

```
    'foreign_sortby' => 'start',
```

with:

```
    'foreign_default_sortby' => 'ORDER BY start ASC',
```